# Executing MySQL Commands from a Java Servlet

Tags: java, mysql, xml, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to get my servlet to output the results of SQL commands entered by the user. Right now, the servlet correctly detects when a command does not include "SELECT", "INSERT", or "DELETE", and outputs an error message. When the command is valid, nothing is outputted. I know this means my problem is likely occurring either where I am trying to connect to the database, or where I am trying to print output to "out".

databaseServlet.java

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class databaseServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private Connection conn;
    private Statement statement;

    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        try {
            Class.forName(config.getInitParameter("databaseDriver"));
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    config.getInitParameter("databaseName"),
                    config.getInitParameter("username"),
                    config.getInitParameter("password"));
            statement = conn.createStatement();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected void doGet (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        out.println("<xml version = \"1.0\"?>");
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD " +
            "XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org" +
            "/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">");
        out.println("<html xmlns = \"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>MySQL Servlet</title>");
        out.println("<style type='text/css'>");
        out.println("body{background-color: blue}");
        out.println("</style>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");

        String query = request.getParameter("query");

        if (query.toLowerCase().contains("select")) {
            //SELECT Queries
            try {
                ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
                ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
                int numberOfColumns = metaData.getColumnCount();
                for(int i = 1; i<= numberOfColumns; i++){
                    out.printf("%20s\t", metaData.getColumnName(i));
                }
                out.println();

                while (resultSet.next()){
                    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++){
                        out.printf("%20s\t", resultSet.getObject(i));
                    }
                    out.println();
                 }
            }
            catch (Exception f) {
                f.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else if (query.toLowerCase().contains("delete") || query.toLowerCase().contains("insert")) {
            //DELETE and INSERT commands
            try {
                conn.prepareStatement(query).executeUpdate(query);
                out.println("\t\t Database has been updated!");
            }
            catch (Exception l){
                l.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else {
            //Not a valid response
            out.println("\t\t Not a valid command or query!");
        }

        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
        out.close();
    }
}
```

dbServlet.jsp

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!-- dbServlet.html -->
<html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>MySQL Servlet</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body{background-color: green;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <h2>This is the MySQL Servlet</h2>
    <form action = "/database/database" method = "get">
    <p>
        <label>Enter your query and click the button to invoke a MySQL Servlet
            <input type = "text" name = "query" />
            <input type = "submit" value = "Run MySQL Servlet" />
        </label>
    </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I thought another potential failure point could be my path to the database file, which is  initialized in my web.xml file. An example I found online included the port, but I'm wondering if I should remove the port number. Does anyone know the default port to use for MySQL?

This is the specific line I'm talking about from the xml file below:
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3309/project4

web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" version="2.4">
  <!-- General description of the web application -->
  <display-name>
    MySQL Servlet
  </display-name>
  <description>
    This web application allows the user to connect to a database, sumbit queries, and make changes.
  </description>
  <!-- Servlet definitions -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>database</servlet-name>
    <description>
        A servlet that handles SQL commands submitted by the user.
    </description>
    <servlet-class>
        databaseServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>databaseDriver</param-name>
        <param-value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>databaseName</param-name>
        <param-value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3309/project4</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>username</param-name>
        <param-value>root</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>password</param-name>
        <param-value>pass</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>database</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/database</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: writing HTMl inside a servlet is way too old and considered bad ..

Comment: you're right! and this is just my prototype to test the database. the final version will be outputting only the results of the query to the jsp front end page (only page the user will see), which will contain all of the html elements. i just want to get the database level working, and know that i have the right output, before finalizing the front-end.

Comment: I seriously hope your finished version also won't accept the SQL as a GET parameter.  The mere sight of that is giving me cold shivers up my spine.

Comment: again, that is to help me troubleshoot the issue. the final version will be using post. really i just need to find out why it isn't connecting to my database. :-/

Comment: I've been told that to connect to my MySQL database, I should be using port # 3306, as that is the default port for MySQL. Sound viable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using port 3309, and needed to use port 3306.

PROBLEM

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3309/project4
```

SOLUTION

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project4
```